# Ubuntu 12.04 энергосбережение SandyBridge

Tags: linux, ubuntu, энергосбережение

На opennet.ru в новости о релизе Ubuntu 12.04 сказано, что в драйвере i915 для карт архитектуры SandyBridge по-умолчанию активирован режим энергосбережения RC6. Но команда    dmesg | grep RC6 не обнаруживает ничего. Однако, если вручную поставить ядро 3.4, то эта же комната покажет, что RC6 включен. Кому в такой ситуации верить — OpenNET-у или своим глазам? И стоит ли ставить 3.4, чтобы добиться нормальной работы энергосбережения?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, речь идёт о "ванильном" ядре. Попрбуйте посмотреть http://www.lesswatts.org/